# Firefox Selenium Error: XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

So I'm trying to access LinkedIn and scrape job posting data. I've successfully done this with Chrome, and wanted to try it with firefox. It should be the exact same code minus initiating the driver -- the html elements should be exactly the same, and are after inspecting them.

Here's a simple form of my test code for Firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#driver = webdriver.Safari('/usr/bin/safaridriver')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/Taras/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs")
search1 = driver.find_element_by_name("keywords")

        #now find the location input element (and clear what is already on there)
clear = driver.find_element_by_class_name("location-clear-icon")
search2 = driver.find_element_by_name("location")
clear.click()
        #now send the queries to the linkedIn page and type it in
search1.send_keys("software engineering")   
search2.send_keys("chicago")
search1.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

linkElements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("job-title-link")
print(linkElements)
links = []

        #iterate through each job result and grab the link to that Job posting -- then append to links array
for a in linkElements:
    linkHref= a.get_attribute("href")
    links.append(linkHref)
print(links)
```

I get up to the point where it gets to the actual search results, but the link array doesn't do anything. The same exact code works in Chrome, however, after trying different html elements, the code does nothing. After inspecting closer and checking the console, I get the above stated error: XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: https://www.linkedin.com/lite/platformtelemetry
Line Number 1, Column 1:

I have no idea what this means, but I assume it is having trouble finding the stated elements. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you using the latest webdriver for firefox?

Comment: Yes, I am. Version 19. I tried un installing and re installing it to no effect